# Counting items in Sharepoint list based on text condition

Tags: power-automate

I have a functioning flow that counts all items on a list very well using the flow PowerApps > Get items > Compose > Create Item

The compose for all items is

```
length(body('Get_items')?['value'])
```

I assume that there is a variant of this that will allow counting of a column based on a text condition.  If I were writing this in Excel I would write

```
=CountIf(Status = "Complete")
```

I'm sure Power Automate flow can perform this I am just not familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a (OData) Filter Query to your Get Items action. This way you don't have to change the expression with the length function.

```
Status eq 'Complete'
```

[image]

Comment: I did as recommended and had the following 'Flow run failed.' error

Column 'Status' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
clientRequestId: d658c85b-153b-486c-af4c-2b6f7b59421f
serviceRequestId: d658c85b-153b-486c-af4c-2b6f7b59421f

Comment: Expiscornovus, the solution worked, I had to go into my list settings and found the name of the column was actually 'field_12'.  After I modified to that the filter worked perfectly. Thanks!